# python3: How to print data from loop under a tabbed header?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a simple python3 script that calculates a rebate onto a paycheque.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


def paycheque():
    pay = float(input("Enter pay rate: "))
    base = int(input("Enter base rate (ie: 733, 875): "))

    header = ['Hours', 'Total', 'Rebate', 'Total+Rebate']
    print("\t".join(header) + "\n")


    for hours in range(20, 41):
        total = round(pay*hours*4*0.8)
        rebate = round(base - ((total - 200) / 2))
        print(hours, total, rebate, total+rebate)


paycheque()
```

How do I make the data from the print statement in the loop tabbed under the header?
I tried putting `"/t".join(hours)` etc in the print but join only works if it is an iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
print(hours, total, rebate, total+rebate, sep='\t')
```